# custom pref getString-android

Tags: android, preferences

I have a custom Pref:

```
public class ImagePreference2 extends Preference {
    private Drawable mIcon;
    Bitmap a;

    public ImagePreference2(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        this.setLayoutResource(R.layout.imagepref2);

        }
}
```

I have added it like this:

```
<en.cold.ImagePreference2
        android:key="test02"
        android:summary="ImagePreference with default icon"
        android:title="ImagePreference" 
        android:selectable="false"
        android:defaultValue="defaultV"
        />
```

I am trying to get string value from PreferencesActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        Log.d("StripedLog",sharedPreferences.getString("test02", "iv"));
    }
```

I get an error:

```
  01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224)
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564):    at en.cold.Settings.onSharedPreferenceChanged(Settings.java:130)
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.notifyListeners(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:475)
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:385)
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564):    at android.preference.Preference.tryCommit(Preference.java:1357)
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564):    at android.preference.Preference.persistBoolean(Preference.java:1623)
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564):    at android.preference.TwoStatePreference.setChecked(TwoStatePreference.java:83)
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564):    at android.preference.TwoStatePreference.onClick(TwoStatePreference.java:69)
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564):    at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:957)
    01-26 16:00:35.031: E/AndroidRuntime(22564
```

Is there I can get string with a custompref?

Comment: From the stack trace it seems as if you have a TwoStatePreference in your activity in addition, and this is of course of type boolean. Did you perhaps use the same key for this preference?

Comment: There must be some other Preference definitions. If your  ImagePreference2 extends only Preference, I do not see how the stack trace can come across TwoStatePreference, if no other preferences are defined.